# How to style cards in css

Tags: html, css

So I have this 2 cards aligned the way i want whit bootstrap and `display: flex;`. When i try to do some some changes in CSS like moving the details class in middle,  or to change the width and height of the card etc it won't work. How can i do it ? Here is the code:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 pop-up">
    <div class="front">
      <div>
        <img class="girlimg" src="girl.jpg" alt="asdasda" />
        <h2 class="activname">Guided hiking tours</h2>
        <button class="activbutt" type="button" name="button">
               SEE DETAILS
               </button>
      </div>
      <div class="details">
        <div class="duration">
          <i class="fas fa-clock">Duration</i>
        </div>
        <div class="people">
          <i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i><br />
          <p>Max adults:10</p>
        </div>
        <div class="kids">
          <i class="fas fa-child"></i><br />
          <p>Max children:3</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 pop-up-2">
  <div class="front">
    <div>
      <img class="girlimg" src="bike.jpg" alt="asdasda" />
      <h2 class="activname">Rent a bike(4 hours)</h2>
      <button class="activbutt" type="button" name="button">
             SEE DETAILS
             </button>
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <div class="duration">
        <i class="fas fa-clock">Duration
               <p>QUARTER DAY</p> </i>
      </div>
      <div class="people">
        <i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i><br />
        <p>Max adults:9</p>
      </div>
      <div class="kids">
        <i class="fas fa-child"></i><br />
        <p>Max children:0</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think it would be easier to understand what you are trying to achieve if you could produce an example in codepen or some other code editor

Comment: The card should look like this: Photo on the top left of the card, details class on the right of the photo, h2 and button under the photo. And i have no idea how to style and move those inside the card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use the card class from bootstrap. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/. Then you will be able to change the default width & height of the card by overriding it from custom CSS.